# How can i create Internal Thread pool for a single Thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I have Quartz Job reading from the Queue and writing to the Queue. Reading is done in main thread and the Writing is done in the Sub thread.

How can i create a pool and get sub thread from that pool

Comment: getting a thread from the pool defeats the point of creating a pool

Answer (score 2):

You can use java Executor framework.

Example:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```